# Translating ER to SQL DDL

Tags: sql, ddl, entity-relationship

When I am translating an ER to SQL DDL I need to Create a table only for the entities or for the relations too?

Comment: I have represented an ER and now I need to create tables (sql ddl) corresponding to that ER

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create tables for both entities and relationships. Also, keep in mind that you have to include foreign keys and link your tables

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type of relationship you have. If it is many to many relationship then it must require a separate table for the relationship itself. Any way you can search on google ER diagram to relational database or look the text book on the relational model chapter of Modern database management sytem of author Hoffer.

Answer (score 0):

You require a CREATE TABLE statement for each ENTITY.

Your relations ships are generally implemented as FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS or FOREIGN KEY INDEXES between those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Each entity becomes a table and each many to many relationship becomes a table.

Add the child columns (FK column) to the (child) tables also. When you create a N:M (many to many) relationship in for example DeZign for Databases, you see that an intersection table is create automatically. The columns which are added automatically are in first instance the columns of the primary key of both tables. You can see that in this video:
http://www.datanamic.com/support/vd-dez001.html